# Angularjs ng-grid change page but lose selectedItems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am new to AngularJS and I started integrating with ng-grid. According to official site http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/, there's a property "selectedItems" that you can set your list of selected items in current scope

```
selectedItems:$scope.mySelectedItems
```

I have no problem of getting selected list items in the current $scope.gridOptions. HOWEVER, I have no idea what to do when I change the page(FOr example using self-defined pagination) or when I need to reload the current gridOptions (for example user launched a new search creteria). **Where I should re-initialize selectedItems?**

I thought of 2 solutions but they wont work:

1.make a whole list of server data and do pagination on client side. It will remain selectedItems and show them correctly on the screen when I change pages. But when user launch a new search, I re-init selectedItems = [] in search Method. Unfortunately, when I select again in grid, selectedItems will always remains **empty**.

2.It's much pratical let server do pagination. In this case, how can I remember selectedItems and show them correctly on screen? Server-side paging exemple of Ng-grid has a bug when you change pages: it keeps selectedItems in $scope but lose them on UI. In this case, where I can init selectedItems?

Comment: stuck at exactly same problem..

Answer (score 2):

got the solution:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/pull/209

bascially specify the primaryKey column of gridOptions

```
        $scope.gridOptions.primaryKey = 'FileRowNo';
```

and everything would work